# How to enable automatic download/or accept download pop-up in IE 11 browser in selenium without using AutoIT

Tags: selenium, browser-automation

I want to click on Save option in the pop up in IE 11 to download a .xlsx file. I am not able to handle it using robot class.
I even tried to disable it in regedit but it doesn't work
[download pop-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t4Jk.png)

Is there any capability for IE or any other solution to handle this pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

Just after downloading the file go to:

- Options -> Downloads
- Right click on the file you want to download without the pop-up message
- Uncheck the Always ask before downloading

Applies for all files of that type

Source: https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/